# Why sometimes it fails to use window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html

I just encounter weird and inconsistent behavior. I type below in w3c online [tester](https://www.w3schools.com/js/).

**test.htm**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<iframe onload="$.getScript('https://mysite.tw/test.js')">
</body>
</html>
```

where in `test.js` (on my server), I write:

```js
alert('get!'); // this is just to confirm the js had indeed loaded
window.location.href="https://amazon.com";
```

Then the alert message jumps, but suddenly the browser blocks the redirect behavior, reporting the server refuses the access.

My first question is that why does this happen? I just want to direct to another site, not to make something complicate or sensitive, like Ajax, etc.

My second question is that I tried the similar code of `test.htm` on another site. And this time the page successfully redirect to amazon. Pretty weird. Is it due to the `https` problem? Or a cross-site security issue?

Comment: Using chrome: 94.0.4606.81. Not sure whether it is related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test.js is in `iframe`, and you may check the response header from https://www.amazon.com/

`x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`

You cannot iframe the web page from other domain.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.
>
> SAMEORIGIN
> The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not pretty sure why. Even though I use the `onload()` event of `iframe` to trigger `document.location.href`, I did not directly `iframe src` to that site. Then why will the mechanism of `iframe` play a role on `onload()` and `$.get.Script` part?

Comment: I guess you tested it in some online html coding tools, where your html is actually embeded in their `iframe`

Comment: Yes. This is the reason! Thank you!